# Node.js on heroku, Cannot read property 'env' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku

I have a node server that sets the port using

```
.listen((process.env.PORT || 5000));
```

which I got from the Heroku test code on Github [here](https://github.com/heroku/node-js-getting-started). This worked earlier, but now I get the following error in my Heroku logs,

```
}).listen((process.env.PORT || 5000));
 at Object.<anonymous> (/app/index.js:35:19)
TypeError: Cannot read property 'env' of undefined
```

I also tried running this locally with foreman run node index.js, which also worked earlier. This now crashes unless I change the port to always be set to 5000. Any help on resolving this issue is greatly appreciated.

**Update**

I tried running node locally (as I get the same error), the variable process is set, and has the property .env also set.

**Server Code**

```
var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    if (req.url == "/debug") {
        res.writeHead(200);
        res.end(debugPage);
    } else {
        var body = '';
        req.on('data', function (data) {
            body += data;
        });
        req.on('end', function () {
            res.writeHead(200);
            data = parsePostData(body);
            if (JSON.stringify(data) == "{}") {
                res.end("No Data"); 
            } else {
                res.end(process(data));
            }
        }); 
      }
}).listen((process.env.PORT || 5000));
```

Comment: Can you post your server code?

Comment: Yes, but it is really messy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to work fine for me :

Server(index.js) :

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 5000));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.get('/', function(request, response) {
  response.send('Hello World!');
});

app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
  console.log('Node app is running on port', app.get('port'));
});
```

Procfile :

```
web: node index.js
```

Demo : https://vikashvverma.herokuapp.com/

Source : https://github.com/vikashvverma/Heroku-Sample

Comment: I tried committing out all most all of my code (so it looked close to that) and it ran, I don't know how I could have broken this but, I'll fix it tomorrow. Thank you.

Comment: @vikash, I'm new to express and node, could you please explain why and what is the difference? Why we have to use `.set()` and `.get(port)` instead of just bare `PORT` variable?